# Selenium Webdriver Js, GetText From Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, selenium

For some of my tests with `Selenium` webdriver in `javacript`, I wanted to get the text from an array of `WebElements` (*which are cells in a table*), but I can't figure out how to do it since the command `getText()` doesn't seem to work when i specify an element from the array like this :

```
id[1].getText()
```

The command is not recognized.

Anyone with an idea ?

Comment: Show more of your code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must reference them properly. Or, in words of Yoda. "UnLearn what you have Learned"

```
WebElement Webtable=driver.findElement(By.id("TableID")); // Replace TableID with Actual Table ID or Xpath
List<WebElement> TotalRowCount=Webtable.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='TableID']/tbody/tr"));

System.out.println("No. of Rows in the WebTable: "+TotalRowCount.size());
// Now we will Iterate the Table and print the Values   
int RowIndex=1;
for(WebElement rowElement:TotalRowCount)
{
      List<WebElement> TotalColumnCount=rowElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
      int ColumnIndex=1;
      for(WebElement colElement:TotalColumnCount)
      {
           System.out.println("Row "+RowIndex+" Column "+ColumnIndex+" Data "+colElement.getText());
           ColumnIndex=ColumnIndex+1;
       }
      RowIndex=RowIndex+1;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but actually, my problem is that the selenium version I use is webdriver Js. To be more specific the thing I would want to do is to verify if a column in a table is sorted well. At first I wanted to compare two by two the cells, but the function findElements doesn't let me to get the content of each webelement after they are stored. Do you have an idea in Javascript ?

Comment: ...Why was this Java code marked as an answer to your JavaScript question?